# Evaluating a condition in qualtrics once the next button is clicked

Tags: javascript, api, qualtrics

I was hoping someone might have some insight you could offer on a problem I have been facing with Qualtrics. Simply, I want Qualtrics to evaluate the contents of a numeric field (i.e. a medical record number, take the five right characters and then compare it against an array of random numbers and return a value of 1 if it is in the list and 0 if it is not in the list). It seems like it should be easy, but because Qualtrics offers no support on the use of Javascript, when the code I prepared didn’t work, I had no one I could call about it… then I found your a post on StackOverflow and thought I’d ask.

I based my answer on the solution found at: [In Qualtrics Surveys, how can you save the response to an item into embedded data when the next button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851340/in-qualtrics-surveys-how-can-you-save-the-response-to-an-item-into-embedded-dat)

It is a year old and I was thinking my solution may have failed because the implementation Qualtrics is using doesn’t support this anymore. Who knows.

I created a simplified version:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{var currentQuestionID = this.getQuestionInfo().QuestionID;
    var resultEmbeddedName = "MRN_RND";
    $('NextButton').onclick = function (event) {
        var responseTextField = document.getElementById(currentQuestionID);
        var randomizercheck = responseTextField.value;
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(resultEmbeddedName, randomizercheck);
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.navClick(event, 'NextButton');
};
});
```

I thought I’d start with something simple and once I am sure it works I can make it more complex. Can’t even get this to work, so I can’t tweak it to do what I need. Again, this is only a waypoint on the way to the solution I was hoping for, but I'm trying to solve the problem incrementally so I can understand where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, not the best solution. Try replacing:

```
var currentQuestionID = this.getQuestionInfo().QuestionID;
```

With:

```
var currentQuestionID = Object.keys(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.QuestionInfo)[0];
```

This is assuming you do not have multiple questions in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that responseTextField isn't the input field. Also, I think you probably want to trigger the event when the text input changes, not when the Next button is clicked. Try this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var currentQuestionID = this.questionId;
    var resultEmbeddedName = "MRN_RND";
    var responseTextField = $(currentQuestionID).select('input.InputText').first();
    responseTextField.observe("keyup", function (event) {
        var randomizercheck = responseTextField.value;
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(resultEmbeddedName, randomizercheck);
    };
});
```

Note: You must define the embedded variable MRN_RND in the survey flow before executing the block with the text input question.